# Is there a Windows tool that will tell me when an entry gets added to a sql table?

Tags: sql, log4net

I have an app doing logging with a log4net AdoNetAppender so I'd like to know when an entry gets added to the log table.  I'm wondering if there is a small app that would sit in the systray and just monitor that table for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your application does not create many log entries or else your requirement would not make much sense. Maybe instead of monitoring the database you might consider using an [SMTP appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender.html) or a [twitter appender](http://twitterappender.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Very low usage.. we're not allowed to install a twitter client but that's a cool idea neverthless.. SMTP might be an option.. I'll think on that..

Answer (score 0):

If your database's tables is a separated files for each table, you can check date of modification table's file using a simple cmd-script